# How to export only content, strictly core content like articles, pages, users, taxonomy ect?

Tags: importing-exporting

**How to export only content, strictly core content like articles, taxonomy ect?**

Is there a way to export content only, no data about modules, only content that will work with drupal core install.

Just data that is  not affected by modules and configurations.

With Joomla I could do this via PHPmyadmin.

Any easy way to do this with Drupal 7, any module?

I see an exclude tables option in backup migrate.

```
You may omit specific tables, or specific table data from the backup 
file. Only omit data that you know you will not need such as cache data, or tables from other applications. Excluding tables can break your Drupal 
install, so do not change these settings unless you know what you're doing.
```

But I'm looking for an include only option, not exclude what you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this

- Use [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module
- Use Node Export Module
- Use Feed Module
- Or you can use web services to achieve this. For example expose data in services and import those data back in the other drupal site. (Very easy approach)
- You need to check the database structure a bit and write a custom php script to take data from one table and insert it into another.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export these data and import it to another drupal site, then you can use [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

> As given in the documentation
>
> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content
>   into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from
>   another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core
>   Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are
>   included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of
>   content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web
>   interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly
>   recommended).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Node Export** Module, its the best and easiest way to Export content

you can download from here https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export

you can find more about this module here http://drupal.org/node/1627916